# Difference between record.data and record.raw

Tags: extjs, rally

I have found as I am developing extjs applications (rally applications) that sometimes the data I need from a record is in record.raw and not in record.data.  What is the difference between the two, and why might this be the case?

EDIT - adding example (a column for the parent that is sortable - one of my other questions)

```
{text: 'Parent', dataIndex: 'Parent',
    doSort: function(state) {
        var ds = this.up('grid').getStore();
        var field = this.getSortParam();
        ds.sort({
            property: field,
            direction: state,
            sorterFn: function(v1, v2){
                if (v1.raw.Parent) {
                    v1 = v1.raw.Parent.Name;
                } else {
                    v1 = v1.data.Name;
                }

                if (v2.raw.Parent) {
                    v2 = v2.raw.Parent.Name;
                } else {
                    v2 = v2.data.Name;
                }
                return v1.localeCompare(v2);
            }
        });
    },
    renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
        var ret = record.raw.Parent;
        if (ret) {
            return ret.Name;
        } else {
            meta.tdCls = 'invisible';
            return record.data.Name;
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example?  Generally we try to avoid using record.data.field or record.raw.field directly in favor of record.get('field')...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data in `raw` is the raw data that has yet to be converted into the types specified in the `fields` config.  Once a `Reader` does that conversion, the converted data is stored in `data`, which is typed based on the `fields`.

You can learn more from the docs about these here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model

Comment: so is it considered poor style - or is it a bad idea - to use the data stored in raw if you find that it has not been converted when you need it?

Comment: @user2544318 fix your model field config and you want have that problem! But the raw data may be useful if you converted values so accessing it is perfectly fine. But as I mentioned above I would not recommend to do it because of a poor field configuration of your model!

Comment: One additional info: raw data will always show the data that was used by the reader to create the model data by using the model field configuration. By the time you normally access this data the reader already finished his job

Comment: is there any method to synchronise data raw with a real data model ?